# Why is my server complaining that Ruby isn't installed when browsing Omega theme directories? (& how to stop it)

Tags: theming

Earlier [I asked about how to disable the SASS / Ruby stuff in Omega 4](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/127409/how-to-disable-sass-in-omega-4). As I understood it from that answer plus other reading, the SASS / Ruby compatibility in Omega 4 does nothing until the user tells it to compile SASS into CSS via Compass or Guard, and can be ignored - and that it's normal to not install Ruby on production servers for Drupal sites using Omega 4, since SASS is a development tool.

Great. I uninstalled Ruby from my production server.

Now I'm seeing this strange error message, while manually copying layout template files from Omega theme to my subtheme:

[image]

It seems to be trying to trigger some Ruby process while performing a simple `cd` change directory operation in my Omega theme folders - and it's failing, complaining that Ruby is not installed. This is interfering with normal activities.

When navigating between Omega 4 subtheme directories using `cd` in SSH, I've also noticed surprising Ruby-related messages.

What's going on here? Something Omega 4 related appears to exist which is trying to respond to folder access attempts by launching a Ruby process. **What is it, and how do I get rid of it?**

*(either that, or my server is haunted)*

Comment: _When navigating between Omega 4 subtheme directories using cd in SSH, I've also noticed surprising Ruby-related messages._ That's the biggest clue that this isn't Omega's 'fault' if you like. A file's existence can't alter the behaviour of `cd`, unless the _server_ is watching for it. You've probably got guard/grunt/something else watching those folders

Comment: That sounds plausible, I'd thought Guard was part of the ruby stack and would disappear when I uninstalled Ruby. So many dependencies for a themer's tool that just writes CSS... I'll research how to kill Guard.

Comment: `ps aux | grep guard`, kill the process, try navigating again. If that works, find out what's instigating that process and kill it

Comment: They aren't really dependencies as much options - I mean obviously compass relies on ruby so you can't use compass without ruby...but guard is optional, you can just `compass compile` or `compass watch` if you prefer. The recent proliferation of these stacks is actually a really good thing, I can't begin to tell you much time they save once you're familiar enough with them to customise your whole front-end dev workflow

Comment: So after lots of googling [it sounds like Guard is a ruby gem](http://www.amazeelabs.com/en/blog/live-reload-sasscompass-guard). Not sure how it's still running, but presumably this means that if I kill the process with the command you gave, Guard is dead for good? And any "guard files" it's created can be safely ignored? I started guard with `drush omega-guard` but drush seems to be unable to *stop* guard.

Comment: For good measure check your PATH environment variable.

Comment: That command will just show you if a process whose name matches "guard" is running - it might not be guard, there are loads of different ways you can set up file watchers. It depends what you installed and set running when you were setting up the stack. If you added any init scripts as part of that process, they might be to blame. It's almost impossible to say without looking at the server

Comment: Oh you ran drush omega-guard...yeah then run `ps`, note the process id, `kill pid`

Comment: I tried the `ps aux | grep guard` command, but it's not finding anything relevant. The thing I need to turn off is whatever `drush omega-guard` turns on, but there seem to be no docs on that and I guess for most Drupallers it "just works" and never needs to be turned off. Thanks for your help, [there's a guard tag on stackoverflow so I've asked if any of them know how to properly kill it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25464782/how-to-disable-guard-after-uninstalling-ruby) (can't believe that just following the install docs for a *theme* has left me knee-deep in server config problems...)

Comment: If I find an answer I'll post the whole thing here as a plain language step-by-step for any would-be themers who also end up in a similar situation through trying to use Omega 4.